# Example of using MyBatis to invoke (DB2) stored procedures?

Tags: java, xml, stored-procedures, db2, mybatis

I am developing a java app for invoking sql stored procedures. There would be many stored procedures which would have different IN and OUT parameters. The procs to be called would be configured via XML file. The java app would just basically run a proc (at a scheduled time, scheduler/bat file) and then collect the stats (the stored proc's OUT parameters) and send details via email. The parts I don't know about yet is defining the XML's for MyBatis.. Would appreciate input and examples of MyBatis implementation for stored proc please? I am not finding any right now. Also if there is a better, cleaner approach to the overall problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert on IBatis, but I did find a couple of examples:

http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/msg10286.html

http://www.apacheserver.net/How-to-get-output-from-stored-procedure-to-ibatis-class-at1039903.htm

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet might help if you using MyBatis

```
<select id="queryid" parameterMap="paramMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {CALL procedureName(#{param1, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
                   #{param2, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER}, 
                   #{param3, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
                   #{param4, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
                   #{param5, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
                   #{param6, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER})}
 </select>

  <parameterMap id="paramMap" type="Map">
    <parameter property="param1" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String" mode="IN"></parameter>
    <parameter property="param2" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="Integer" mode="IN"></parameter>
    <parameter property="param3" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String" mode="IN"></parameter>
    <parameter property="param4" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String" mode="IN"></parameter>
    <parameter property="param5" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="String" mode="OUT"></parameter>
    <parameter property="param6" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="Integer" mode="OUT"></parameter>
 </parameterMap>
```